# TIBCO Business Works HTTP connection

Tags: tomcat, tibco, tibco-business-works

In the TIBCO Business Works HTTP connection palette, the Connection resource in the designer has two options for Server Type:

1. Tomcat
2. HTTPComponent

I would like to know on what basis do we select the server type?

Answer (score 1):

You can find an answer to your question in chapter 6 of the [TIBCO ActiveMatrix BusinessWorks Palette Reference](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activematrix_businessworks/5.13.0/doc/pdf/tib_bw_palette_reference.pdf):

> Two types of servers are available for the HTTP Connection resource: Tomcat and HTTPComponent.
>
> Tomcat has a synchronous request response paradigm and can be used in scenarios where high throughput is important. To achieve a good throughput with Tomcat, the maxprocessor value should be almost equal to the number of concurrent requests the server can handle. Note that increasing the maxprocessor count also increases the memory footprint.
>
> HTTPComponent is a light-weight and scalable server based on NIO which can be useful in scenarios where handling thousands of requests in a resource efficient manner is more important than the throughput. HTTPComponent server gives a consistent throughput for any number of concurrent requests with little or no increase in its worker thread (maxprocessor thread).

Comment: Something that I also noticed when using the Tomcat server is that you cannot specify a hostname or DNS that does not belong to the server that your BW service is running on. This is not ideal if you BW servers are running behind a load balancer and you want a WSDL to reflect the true endpoint. Using HTTPComponent server allows you to specify any host name.